# Change reference to different model rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

How can I migrate the `Referral` table to point to point to the `PatientProfile` id instead of the `User` id for an existing database (i.e. would like to migrate all existing rows)?

```
class User
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true
  has_many :referrals

class PatientProfile
  has_one :user, as: :profile

class Referral
  belongs_to :user
```

I could accomplish this by simply making a migration and renaming the `user_id` column to be `patient_profile_id` and changing the reference in the model, however that would not migrate over existing records.

Comment: Why do you want to do it?  Is it simply to access the patient profile from the referral you might be able to simply do `has_one profile, through: :user`, not sure if it'll work with it being a polymorphic association

Comment: @japed it'll clean up my code significantly. I should have been referencing the profile all along and never the user (There are multiple profiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't simply change the column name.  I'd do something like this

```
class AddPatientProfileToReferrals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :referrals, :patient_profile_id
    add_index :referrals, :patient_profile_id

    Referral.reset_column_information

    Referral.includes(:user).find_each do |referral|
      referral.update_attribute(:patient_profile_id, referral.user.profile_id)
    end

    remove_column :referrals, :user_id
  end
end
```

You probably want to make sure the referrals have a user, and you can simply reverse the process to write the down method.

Comment: Data migrations should not go in the ActiveRecord migrations: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/data-migrations-in-rails